# Python - Nested if statement - else go back to original if statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am a total noob. I am trying to loop back to the original raw_input when inside the second if statement. i want to loop the nested if statement with an option to go back to the original raw_input. hope this makes sense. Thanks

```
import os
os.system("clear")
start= raw_input("SUP?\n\n1: Repo\n2: Installed\n...")
if int(start)== 1:
    os.system("clear")
    while True:
        repo= raw_input("\n1: Search repo\n2: Install\n3: Back\n...")
        if int(repo)== 1:
            os.system("clear")
            search= raw_input("What are you trying to search?\n")
            os.system("apt-cache search " + search)
        if int(repo)== 2:
            os.system("clear")
            inst= raw_input("What would you like to install?\n")
            os.system("sudo apt-get install " + inst)    
        else???      
if int(start)==2:
    os.system("clear") 
    ins=raw_input("\n1: Search Installed\n2: Delete installed\n...")
```

Comment: You need to use a loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "original" `raw_input`? you mean the line with `start = ...`?

Comment: To understand how looping works, as a beginner I'd advise you to write every task your code would be doing. You would follow each and every step, including looping 10 times if needed, in order to understand what you're doing. You should also try **easier** exercices about loop first.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your code inside a function and call the function again.
Now since you are new to python, function helps in breaking up your code into functional parts. Read more about them [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial&ved=0ahUKEwjd8Zu2pYXZAhWE6Y8KHSUSBq4QFgg9MAE&usg=AOvVaw2qIZenf5HS1OVLpvQj1ZM4) and [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm&ved=2ahUKEwjd8Zu2pYXZAhWE6Y8KHSUSBq4QFjALegQIExAB&usg=AOvVaw2mm8HITabbi3UaZF7W0TZU)

A function calling itself is called **Recursion**. This is an important concept and will come handy. You can read about [recursion here.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php&ved=2ahUKEwiP46KQpoXZAhWIq48KHcvOAKYQFjAAegQIDxAB&usg=AOvVaw1dLEvFaw99cEjGWMfwP_rz)

```
def myFunc():
    start=raw_input("blah blah...")
    '''Your conditions and statements'''
    if #condition:
        #loop back to raw_input()
        myFunc()
    else:
        #your statements
```